# How to fill a dataframe with boucle for in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 6 csv files contain 3 columns, I want to get the maximum value for each column in each file and put it in another new dataframe that I already created

I created a dataframe and a for boucle for to read all csvs and extract the needed data. the problem when I executte the code he full the dataframe with the values of the last csv file in all columns

```
       Maxx     Maxy    Maxz 
1 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012    
2 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
3 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
4 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
5 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012    
6 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012


f <- data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 3, nrow = 6))
colnames(f) <- c("Maxx","Maxy","Maxz")
head(f)

a <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
for (i in a)
{
  b <- read.csv(i)
  j <- i
  for (j in 1:6) {

    f[j,1] <- max(as.numeric(as.character(b$X)), na.rm=TRUE)
    f[j,2] <- max(as.numeric(as.character(b$X.1)), na.rm=TRUE)
    f[j,3] <- max(as.numeric(as.character(b$X.2)), na.rm=TRUE)

                 }    
}

head(f)

       Maxx     Maxy    Maxz 
1 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012    
2 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
3 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
4 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012   
5 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012    
6 -5.975904 7.614458 3.53012
```

I expect to have the same strcture of table with 18 diffrents value, for each file and column the appropriate value. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by boucle?

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the files in `a`, read them, for each column find the max and bind the results together for all files.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(a, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    sapply(df, max, na.rm = TRUE)
}))
```

where

```
a <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
```